# Getting instantiated object in another JavaScript function

Tags: javascript

I have a ball.js loaded to index.html:

```
var ball;

function initBall(){
    ball = new Ball();
)

//jquery
$(document).ready(function(){
    initBall();
})

// called from index.html file
function getBall(){
    console.log(ball); // the value is 'undefined'
}
```

Question: How do I access the ball object that has already been instantiated in initBall()?

Comment: I'm pretty sure what you expect to work will work.  The problem, I'm guessing, is that you are calling getBall() before initBall() is called.  Would be helpful if you included the code that is calling getBall().

Comment: Thanks @bluefeet. I did a console.log() on both methods and found that getBall() is called before initBall().

Comment: I don't know how to mark your commend as answer... =\

Comment: Ha, no worries.  Your thanks is enough.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    initBall();
})
```

means 'run initBall after the document is ready' -> you may be calling getBall sooner than the document fires the ready event.

Another issue could be that "ball" is not set at all. Try adding one line to the initBall function to log the ball object right after you set it.

```
function initBall(){
    ball = new Ball();
    console.log('initBall', ball);
)
```